# How to use Custom Field Image cropped size in Content Field repeater without plugin Timber?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I implemented my Flexible Content Field and one of my layouts includes Image. I need to crop its size.

I added my custom size in `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_theme_setup' );
function wpdocs_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( 'custom-crop', 220, 180, true ); // (cropped)}
```

My HTML code, where would like to call custom crop size :

```
if( have_rows('top_informations') ):

    while ( have_rows('top_informations') ) : the_row(); ?>

       <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image')?>">


                                <h2><?php the_sub_field('title_text')?> </h2>


                           <?php endwhile;

                           // echo '</ul>';

                        endif;`
```

Line with  represents sub field image. My custom field Image is set to return URL.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please proofread and properly format your posts. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the image field 'Return Value' to 'Image ID' and use the following code.

```
<?php $thumb_img=wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'),'custom-crop'); ?>
<img src="<?php echo $thumb_img[0]; ?>">
```

If still not working, remove the `add_image_size` from `wpdocs_theme_setup` function, and add this directly in 'functions.php'.

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array('post') ); //add all custom post types which need featured image
    add_image_size( 'custom-crop', 220, 180, true );
}
```

You then need to regenerate the thumbnails using the plugin in my comment.

Comment: It seems geat, but that code return my full size :( Do not know why.. is my  custom-crop correctly added in functions.php ?? It looks like custom-crop is not recognized ...

Comment: If the image uploaded before adding the `add_image_size` function, you need to regenerate the thumbnails. Use https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ plugin (or any equivalent) for this.